# Independent variables using $\min$ and $\max$

Tags: probability, independence

> $A$ and $B$ both toss the same biased coin. The probability that the coin shows heads is $p$. Let $X$ be the number of times $A$ tosses the coin until it shows heads. Let $Y$ be the number of times $B$ tosses the coin until it shows heads. Let $S=X+Y$, $T$ be the maximum of $X$ and $Y$, $U=|X-Y|$, and $W$ be the minimum of $X$ and $Y$. Show that $U$ and $W$ are independent and that no other pair of the four variables is.

I have already solved this question by just going through the geometric summations to get the distributions, giving some counterexamples etc and it all works out. However while solving this I was intersted in whether I could use the formula $\min\{X,Y\}=\frac{1}{2}(X+Y-|X-Y|)$. That is, $W=\frac{1}{2}(S-U)$. There is an analogous formula for $T$, $T=\frac{1}{2}(S+U)$. I don't really think I am experienced enough to reason it on my own using this so I have turned here for help.

Considering $T$ and $S$, we can easily argue $P(S=2 \cap T=3)=0\neq P(S=2)P(T=3)$. However, I don't think this immediately implies $(T,U)$ and $(U,S)$ are dependent because although we have $U=2T-S$, it could be that $T=\frac{S+1}{2}$ therefore $U=1$, and so would be independent of the others.

So my question is, can we use these relations to help with this problem?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does "no of pair of the four..." mean "no other pair of the four..."?

Comment: @stochastic13 It does